# Where is the User's Admin Bar Preference stored? I want it to default to off for new users

Tags: admin

In the `profile.php` admin page there is a checkbox for the *Toolbar*: **Show Toolbar when viewing site**.

I can't seem to find where this option is stored in the database.  I would have thought it would be in the `wp_usermeta` table ... but I don't see it.

My goal is to set the default value of this to "off" for new users.  Then, of course, they would have the option to turn it on if they wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the usermeta upon user registration.

Try adding this to functions.php and then adding a new user:

```
add_action('user_register', 'update_usermeta_bar', 10, 1);

function update_usermeta_bar($user_id)
{

    update_user_meta($user_id, 'show_admin_bar_front', "false");
}
```

Comment: That's so strange -- I feel like this should work but it is still being set to true after registration ... I wonder if WP is setting this user_meta field after the `user_register` hook is called and overwriting what we put there.  Because my other `update_user_meta` calls are working in the same place.

Comment: I got it: false had to be in quotes ... otherwise I don't think it's storing the actual value 'false': `update_user_meta($user_id, 'show_admin_bar_front', 'false');`

Comment: I believe any value other than "true" should work. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the usermeta table, there is a key called "show_admin_bar_front" Try this query:

`SELECT * 
FROM  wp_usermeta 
WHERE meta_key LIKE  'show_admin_bar_front'`

Comment: There it is -- I don't know why I didn't see that the first time I looked.  Need glasses.  Thanks.