# Default new users to no admin bar

Tags: wp-admin, users, wp-login-form

I want to be able to default all new users created with the wp_login (register) box to have the user option:

*Show Toolbar when viewing site*

set to unchecked. I have the facility to then jump into wp-admin from within my website as and when required, but I don't want the black bar always showing. Its all works perfectly fine if the option is unchecked, but any new user is checked by default which means until I can manually uncheck it I have a problem.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the User's Admin Bar Preference stored? I want it to default to off for new users](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136062/where-is-the-users-admin-bar-preference-stored-i-want-it-to-default-to-off-for)

Comment: Thanks, I did search for an answer, clearly not well enough. Thanks for your time.